# how can I Separate Refresh token with Get access token?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I created "test-App" application in API Manager WSO2 with the grant types of "refresh-token" "SAML2", "PASSWORD" "Client Credentials" and "JWT"

I also Created a "test"

To use the webservices behind API manager, First, I should call https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token) to get a access-token

Unfortunately, if I call the link again, instead of receiving the same access-token, the system will generate a **new access-token** and the previous access-token would be expired. ( I think this link is more like refresh token rather than get the access token).

So, How can I Separate getting available access-token  and Refresh-token link in WSO2 API Manager ?

Comment: curl -k -X POST https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token -d "grant_type=password&username=Username&password=Password"
-H "Authorization: Basic hjhjhjhjhjhjjjjjjjjjjkjhkhkhkhkhkhkhkjhkjhkjhkhkjhjkhkjhk"

Answer (score 0):

In the latest versions of API Manager you have JWT tokens. When you request a new token it always generates a new token. But it doesn’t revoke the previous access token.

In the earlier versions of APIM, opaque tokens were supported and it has a different behavior. When you request a token, if it is not expired you get the same token.

Please read more about refresh grant here https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/api-security/oauth2/grant-types/refresh-token-grant/

Comment: As I checked right now, Unfortunately the previous JWT token expired. should I change any setting ??

Comment: I Add the access token Curl in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not done any other configuration changes, invoking https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token URL will always generate a new JWT token without expiring the earlier one. However, the token validity can be changed in the Dev Portal while generating the access token.